# React Native Android application not responding on POCO X2 phone

Tags: android, react-native

[enter image description here][1]My React Native Android application works perfectly fine on POCO X2  , if I install it via USB. But if I assemble the .apk or .aab ,the app get installed but do not perform action like Login or register.
Please note , this issue is specific for POCO X2 phone. It is working on other phones.
Phone model POCO-X2 , Android 10 , API 29.
I am attaching my build.gradle config:

- List item

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl1sM.jpg
```

Comment: Hello Ashish. Are you testing on a real or virtual device ?

Comment: Hi @fegoulart , I am testing on real device.

Comment: This issue is specific only on POCO X2 , which i have recently purchased.This application is working perfectly on my older mobile phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. I tried to install same application bundle on other android 10 devices and it wasn't working on any.
That means something was blocking the http request made by the application and the actual issue was that latest RN versions target recent Android SDK that blocks insecure HTTP connections automatically.

Just by adding this : android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" inside manifest file inside  tag , my problem was solved.[Attached the link here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24361)

Another solution for this problem is to avoid making http request as they are insecure, and use https instead.

### <application ... android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"